# Can you purposely delay the sound inside the Windows OS backwards?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, audio, lag, latency

I got a pair of google max speakers which are hooked up via a 3.5 mm jack but they stream the audio input to each other and split it into a right and left channel which introduces a delay of 1 to 1.5 seconds when for example clicking the windows soundbar in the taskbar when changing the volume. Same thing when I brows the web and watch videos etc.

My question is if it is possible for windows to somehow compensate and put the audio that is getting played about 1 second back in time? Think of a video editing software where you slide the audio track to the left side to compensate for the audio delay so that the video syncs up with the sound.

I would loose those first second/s in the beginning but I can live with that. That is a lot better than a audio track which is painfully behind the video track.

Or is it possible to do this in for example Ubuntu?

Thanks in advance for the input!

Comment: For video players, sure it is able to be done and if often an option in the player software, but how do you expect an operating system to put sounds before the event that caused them? It would require the OS to know what you were going to do before you actually did it.

Comment: @Mokubai Yes exactly, I know the VLC player has these features. That's my thought too. That is why I am wondering if Windows has some kind of "event listener" which can indicate that some kind of media is being played and jump forward in the video track to get in sync with the delayed audio track. I figure that I can not be the only person with this kind of a problem.

I am otherwise searching for a chrome plug-in that can do the mentioned thing above and start this delay compensation when some clip is being played.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there is a [Bluetooth cache delay setting](https://www.reddit.com/r/googlehome/comments/8t8nho/fix_google_home_bluetooth_lag_issue/) for the speakers, "You have to change this in developer settings. It can be unlocked by clicking the build number several times."

There are also media players such as [MPC-HC](https://mpc-hc.org/), which works well in wine, [Snap](https://snapcraft.io/mpc-hc) or [built for Ubuntu](http://sysads.co.uk/2014/08/25/install-media-player-classic-home-cinema-ubuntu-os/), which [can delay audio or video to resync them](http://aboutdevice.com/how-to-fix-audio-and-video-out-of-sync-mpchc). That said, a one-second delay is a bit much to fix, and if the cache delay varies, then it will be impossible to sync well.

Comment: There are developer setting in windows? Sounds more like you are talking about Android in the first sentence. Yes I think VLC on both Windows and Linux can archive that but I want this to work on the web and in the best case scenario in the whole OS.

Comment: @MaxPower. nothing mentioned Windows... read the site referenced.

Comment: Oh sorry, my mobile browser somehow managed to not show a underline or other indication of there being hyperlinks in the text. So everything has to be pre-downloaded so to say to get this working, alright. Thanks for the tips!